# .htaccess Won't Work Correctly

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I have a Rewrite in my .htaccess that works correctly with what I originally planned.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

I have index.php?id=4 going to /4/.

**The Problem**

If I try to go to another page though, it always brings me back to index.php.  For example, I have a page called "Update.php".  If I go to update.php, I'm redirected to index.php

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: maybe change `^/` to `0-9`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Above your rule

This only rewrites when the file doesn't exist

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!  I'll accept the answer in a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #check if requested file not found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #check if requested directory not found
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA] #then apply the rule
```

The above rule first checks if requested URI not a real file and folder, then applying the rule, this prevents to redirect when opening existing file and folder.